# Page shows same user with 1 and 6 reputation at the same time!

Tags: bug, reputation, users, information-display

There seems to be a race condition or caching issue when rendering questions and answers on a page, wrt looking up a user's reputation.

A few minutes ago, I browsed to [McAfee blocking PDFs](https://superuser.com/questions/455886/mcafee-blocking-pdfs) on Super User, and noticed that [the user](https://superuser.com/users/149405/john-b) (who had answered his own question) was listed as having 6 rep in the question but 1 rep in the answer:

[image: Unpossible!]

I'm guessing another user upvoted the question at almost the same time that I loaded the page.

Is this a display glitch, or is the user merely in a superposition of states?

Comment: They have different user IDs. So it's not the same account.

Comment: Note that if an answer comes from the same account as the question, the answer's user has the same (in this case, blue) highlighting as on the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not impossible. They're actually two different users with the same name and apparently IP/email. They should be merged.

Meet [John B (149405)](https://superuser.com/users/149405/john-b) and [John B (149746)](https://superuser.com/users/149746/john-b).

Comment: Looks like you're right. That's the first thing I thought, but I thought I checked it....